# Array compression and search in C++(basics)

Tags: c++, arrays, module

So I need help with array of 20 elements.

I need to find each element Absolute value, and if it's value is less than 1 then remove this element from array. Afterwards at the end of array put 0 in place of a removed element.

So im looking for some functions which will help me to do this.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>



int OddSumm(int arr[], int lenght)
{   
    int i,p,z;
    p=0;        
    for (i=0; i<lenght; i++)
        if(arr[i]%2!=0 && arr[i]!=0 ){
            p+=arr[i];
        }   
    return p;
}

int SummBetweenNegativeNumbers(int arr[], int lenght) {
    int s,i,r,z;
    s=0;    

    for (i=0; i<lenght; i++)
        if(arr[i]<0){
            i++;
           r=i;
           for (i=r; i<lenght; i++)
           if(arr[i]<0){
           --i;
           z=i; 
             for (i=r; i<=z; i++)
            s+=arr[i];

}
}
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int var;
    int i,arr[20];
    int s,p,lenght;
    lenght=20;


    {
        printf("Type in  %d elements \n",lenght);
            for (i=0; i<lenght; i++)
                scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    p=OddSumm(arr,lenght);
    s=SummBetweenNegativeNumbers(arr,lenght);

    printf("\n\t 1a)Odd numbers summ: %d",p);
    printf("\n\t 1b)Elements summ between negativ numbers: %d", s);
    printf("\n\t 2)Compressed array: ");
        for(i=lenght-1; i>=0; i--)
            printf(" %d",arr[i]);
        printf("\n\n");
    system("pause");


return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Your code is unreadable. I recommend using English symbols (names of functions and variables). In addition to that, the question itself is unclear IMO. What does `I need to put each element in module(abs)` mean???

Comment: Absolute value is what i mean

Comment: most of the code seems to be unrelated to the question. I dont think you need `OddSum` or `SummBetweenNegativeNumbers` to get the absolute value of the elements. Please provide a [mcve] (emphasis on minimal)

Comment: BTW, this code looks like pure C, so despite the fact that you can compile it also as C++, I would recommend change the tag on this question.

Comment: Since it's an array of integers, the only elements whose absolute value is less than 1 are zero. Is the question "how do I move the zeros to the end of the array"?

Answer (score 2):

1. use `std::transform` to transform your data
2. use `std::remove` to compact these nonzeros
3. use `std::fill` to fill padding zeros

---

example code

```
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int my_function(int value){
   value = std::abs(value);
   return value<1 ? 0:value;
}

int main()
{
    int v[]={0,1,2,-4,-5,3};
    std::transform(std::begin(v),std::end(v),std::begin(v),my_function);
    auto end=std::remove(std::begin(v),std::end(v),0);
    std::fill(end,std::end(v),0);
    for(auto value : v)std::cout<<value<<' ';
}
```